# cleanly adding line breaks to XML comments in visual studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, documentation, xmldocument

is there any way to add a break to xml documentation without using a br tag? In the below example I want the text in the steps node to be cleanly displayed in the output. Ex, line breaks are present in the output

```
///<summary> this is a unit test </summary>
///<steps>
/// 1. do something
/// 2. do something else
/// 3. save that something
///</steps>
```

If I use a br tag the tag will be displayed if I open the xml file in IE. At least for now I want to avoid using something like sandcastle as I have very minimal display needs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I gave CDATA a try but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
///<para>1. Do Something</para>
```

And

```
///<para/>1. Do Something
```

might also work, for 1-liners anyway.

Now if you want a list…

```
///<list>
///<item>Do Something</item>
///<item/>Experiment to see if this works
///</list>
```

[Here is a nice, concise article on XML comment tags](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/07/21/wcovb_xml-comments-part-1.aspx)
.